# SIGNAL SQLSTATE Inside Trigger Failing

Tags: oracle, triggers, sql-update

I have a Product table with 4 columns. 2 columns are price. If the ListPrice column is updated to below a specified amount (StandardCost * 1.2) then the update should fail and the old ListPrice should remain. I am attempting to use a SIGNAL SQLSTATE error to prevent the update from occurring if the criteria are met.

I've been combing Google and tried various variations in the syntax, but I keep hitting the following error while compiling my trigger - "PLS-00103 - Encountered the symbol 'SQLSTATE' when expecting one of the following: := , ( @ %"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Product_Price_Check 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ListPrice ON Product 
FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE 
min_price NUMBER(10, 2); 
new_price NUMBER(10, 2);

BEGIN 
min_price := (:OLD.StandardCost*1.2); 
new_price := (:NEW.ListPrice);
IF (new_price < min_price) THEN
            -- Rolls back an explicit or implicit transaction to the beginning of the transaction
            dbms_output.put_line('the price can’t be below ' || TO_CHAR(min_price)); 
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Insert/update failed';
 END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I don't think Oracle database has the `SIGNAL` statement. MySQL does, but the rest of your code _is_ Oracle... Which database are we talking about?

Comment: By the way, "combing Google" for syntax is usually less productive than reading the product manual.

Answer (score 0):

As mustaccio said, you're mixing MySQL syntax with an Oracle trigger. You want [`raise_application_error`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/errors.htm#i1871):

```
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.ListPrice < (:OLD.StandardCost*1.2) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001,
      'the price can’t be below ' || TO_CHAR(:OLD.StandardCost*1.2));
  END IF;
END;
/
```

This won't roll back the transaction, just the update statement. The caller will receive the exception and decide how to handle it - whether to try again, roll back, or commit any other changes already made.

This assumes the old standard cost cannot be null. You might also want to specify a format model for the `to_char()`.

Also don't rely on `dbms_output` for informing the caller about anything, as you won't know if the caller is looking at or doing anything with the buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will be making my adjustments on Wednesday and will update this thread.